# Como ejecutar 2 funciones en paralelo y esperar por ellas en c#

Tags: c#, mvc, funciones, task

No había visto nada hasta ahora de ejecución en paralelo de 2 o mas funciones y resulta que me hace falta implementarlas de esta manera. El motivo?? página web lenta. 
Tengo que consultar 2 Procedimientos Almacenados que se demoran de una BD lejos del server (que ya de por si es lento) de publicación de mi sitio y estaba pensando en aprovechar el paralelismo y no esperar a que se termine la 1ra para empezar con la 2da. Utilizo MVC.

Pudieran darme alguna idea???

Mi código es este, en el .cs

```
internal static GenericResponse Index()
        {           
            prediccionHomeModel datos = new prediccionHomeModel();
//independiente 
            var filtros = GetFiltros();
//independiente
            List<salidaModeloModel> salidasModelo = GetAllSalidaModelo().Items;
//dependiente de filtro
            List<alertaModel> alertas = getAlertas(filtros).Items;
//dependiente de todos
            datos.grupos = getAlertasGrupos(datos.filtros, alertas, salidasModelo);
//dependiente del anterior
            datos.labelsIndex = getLabels(datos.grupos);         

            return datos;
        }
```

Quisiera que se ejecutaran en paralelo Getfiltros() y GetAllSalidaModelo() que son los que traen los datos y posteriormente hacer todo lo demás.

Estuve utilizando Task y se rompe al hacer la consulta, y sin Task esto si funciona bien.

```
    internal static GenericResponse Index()
            { 
prediccionHomeModel datos = new prediccionHomeModel();
////metodos paralelos 
           var TareaA = Task<filtroHeaderModel>.Factory.StartNew(() => GetFiltros());
            var TareaC = TareaA.ContinueWith((p) => getAlertas(p.Result));
            var TareaB = Task<salidaModeloListModel>.Factory.StartNew(() => GetAllSalidaModelo());

            Task.WaitAll(new Task[] { TareaA, TareaB, TareaC });
            datos.grupos = getAlertasGrupos(TareaA.Result, TareaC.Result.Items, TareaB.Result.Items);
            datos.labelsIndex = getLabels(datos.grupos);
            datos.filtros = TareaA.Result;

                return datos;
            }
```

esta es la consulta al SP

```
internal static DataSet GetFiltros()
        {
            DataSet result = null;           
            try
            {
                string codePais = GuidTX.codeLocation();
                Log.ActivityTimerStart(Log.LOG_DATA_ACCESS, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name + "." + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
                var classMethod = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name, Const.DotSymbol, System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);

                result = DataAccessFactory.CreateSpDataAccessInstance(classMethod, "SQL-APM", "[spGetMaestroModoFalla]").Execute();
            }
            catch (CredentialException cex)
            {
                throw cex;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(Log.LOG_DATA_ACCESS, "Error en " + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name + "." + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex);
                throw new Exception("Error en " + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name + "." + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.ActivityTimerEnd(Log.LOG_DATA_ACCESS);
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Esta retorna null, y no debe ser.
Saludos y gracias por leer.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar async/await. Mas información aqui: [microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

Mensionas paralelismo. No es correcto. El paralelismo se utiliza en un ordenador, para aprovechar ejecución de tareas en diferentes nuecleos del procesador. Para que una tarea vaya a nucleo 1, otra a nucleo 2, etc. Ya que si no lo haces, no aprovechas del todo procesador. Pero esto es para apurar mucho, el Framework.NET ya se encarga de hacer que CPU trabaje mejor aún que no utilizas paralelismo de forma expresa. Eso si, es una herramienta muy util. Basicamente tienes que utilizar biblioteca TPL o PLINQ. Aqui hay mucha información hacerca de esto y muy bien explicado: [docs de microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/)

Y si quieres hacer algo muy muy a medida, puedes utilizar tambien el System.Threading de toda la vida para crear subprocesos: [enlace a threading](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?view=netframework-4.8)